# Calcular e Recalcular

Tags: javascript, jquery

fiz essa função pra buscar as notas preenchidas e quando faço no onload calcula certinho.
Quando uso a função onkeypress="somaNotas" que esta em cada input ele calcula tudo errado.

Alguém tem ideia do que estou fazendo errado.

```
function somaNotas(){
jQuery('input[name="nota"]').each(function(media=0){
    if (jQuery(this).val()!==''){
        var idElem = jQuery(this).data('id');
        var nota = parseInt(jQuery('.media'+idElem).data('media'));
        var notaProva = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());

        nota += notaProva;
        media++;
    }
    mediaSoma = (nota/media).toFixed(1);
    jQuery('.media'+idElem).html(mediaSoma).data('media',nota);
    jQuery('.notas'+jQuery(this).data('id')).html(nota);
});
}
onload = somaNotas();
```

Comment: `onload` do que?, `window.onkeypress` ?

Comment: utilize um [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) nesta pergunta. Para testar antes de publicar [vá para o Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/269862)

Comment: é um form que é grado em php a quantidade de notas varia de acordo com o nivel.
Então quando carrega a pagian eu uso o onload pra executar a funcão acima.
E nos campos nota tem o onpress com a mesma função pra recalcular